# Where to find volume mount icon on Leopard

Tags: macos, icons, dmg

I want to change the default icon of a dmg, I'ld like to do like skype or dropbox which use the default image volume icon, but I don't manage to find it with the finder. Do you have any idea where I could find it?

Thanks for your answer, 
Boris

Comment: The icon per default might be called removable.icns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I didn't find the icon in the finder but you can download the full icon set here : [here](http://rs110l33.rapidshare.com/files/85866864/4367342/iLeopard_Icon_Pack_SE.zip)

Also if you want to set the dmg icon from the cmd line :

- **cp < your file.icns > < your mounted image path >.VolumeIcon.icns** (make sure your dmg is writable)
- **SetFile -a C < your mounted image path >**

The second command line is used to tell the dmg to use the icon once mounted.

If you want to make an icns from any kind of image, have a look at this freeware : [img2icns](http://www.img2icnsapp.com/)

Comment: That icon set download link is broken nowadays, but I found the icon in: /System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/Removable.icns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set custom volume icon then use below command

```
/*
SetFile -c icnC will change the creator of the file to icnC
*/
SetFile -c icnC /<your path>/.VolumeIcon.icns
```

Now create read/write dmg

```
/*
to set custom icon attribute
*/
SetFile -a C /Volumes/dmgName
```